# Wrong text in selects

Tags: django

I have these model and admin files. It works nice but when I select one activity while adding new Gym Object in the select I see "Activity object" instead of the Activity title.

How can I change these?

```
# Model
from django.db import models

class Activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Gym(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    where = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    timetable = models.TextField()
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activity, through='GymActivity')

class GymActivity(models.Model):
    gym = models.ForeignKey(Gym)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)

# Admin
from django.contrib import admin
from gym.models import Gym, Activity, GymActivity

class GymActivityInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Gym.activities.through
    extra = 6

class GymAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'pub_date']
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['name']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        (None,               {'fields': ['where']}),
        (None,               {'fields': ['description']}),
        (None,               {'fields': ['timetable']}),
    ]
    inlines = [GymActivityInline]

class ActivityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title']

admin.site.register(Gym, GymAdmin)
admin.site.register(Activity, ActivityAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing [`__unicode__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) on the models

Do this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.title
```

[If you are using Python 3.x, just replace `__unicode__` with `__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)